# Is it possible to have logic in PHP's preg_replace function's replace parameter?

Tags: php, regex

Here is some PHP that I want to replace with something else.

```
Ks. <?kys(1959,"kysymys 1959")?>.
Ks. <?kys(1959)?>.
```

I have this regular expression, which finds both and works fine:

```
<\?kys\((\d+)(,"([\s\S]+)")?\)\?>
```

I tested (and designed) it with Regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/kcDpN3/1

So there will at least be match $1. But there can also be matches $2 and $3. Is it possible to have `preg_replace` replace the matches with the following logic: if $3, use $3; else use $1?

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: No, because it will just concatenate both matches, which isn't what I want. I want either or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/pRgef):

```
$str = 'Ks. <?kys(1959,"kysymys 1959")?>.
Ks. <?kys(1959)?>.';
$re = '/<\?kys\((\d+)(?:,"([^"]+)")?\)\?>/';

echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return empty($m[2]) ? $m[1] : $m[2];
}, $str);
```

Here, the second group in your pattern was turned into non-capturing one (`?:` added after `(`) and now there are only two groups to handle.

The `$m` is the whole match object, and if Group 2 is empty, the replacement is Group 1 value (`$m[1]`). Else, it is Group 2 value, `$m[2]`.

Note I also replaced `[\s\S]+` with `[^"]+` to make it match till the first `"`. Replace with `.*?` and add `/s` flag if there can be `"` inside Group 2.